# Python loop controler continue is not working properly

Tags: python

As I know, "continue" will jump back to the top of the loop. But in my case it's not jumping back, continue don't like me :(

```
for cases in files:
  if ('python' in cases.split()):
    execute_python_scripts(cases.split())
    elif run_test_case(cases.split()):
      continue
    else:
      logger("I am here")
      break
```

In my case `run_test_case()` gives 1, 2, 3, 4 etc... But it always performs first(1) and jump to the else part. So I am getting the "I am here" message. It should not work like this. As I am using "continue", it should jump to the for loop.

Following is the `run_test_case()`:

```
def run_test_case(job):
  for x in job:
    num_of_cases = num_of_cases - 1
    test_type = x.split('/')
    logger(log_file,"Currently "+ x +"hai!!")
    if test_type[0] == 'volume':
      backdoor = test_type[1].split("_")
      if backdoor[0] == 'backdoor':
        return get_all_nas_logs()
      else:
        if perform_volume_operations(x,num_of_cases) == False:
          return False
        else:
      logger(log_file,"wrong ha!!")
```

Why is it always going to the else part, without jumping back to the for loop? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what happens if you uncomment `print test_type[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `elif run_test_case(cases.split()):` you are calling the `run_test_case` method, that will run your code to evaluate the result for the `elif` condition.

It only enters the block delimited by `elif` (in your case, `continue`), if the result of that method evaluates to `True`, otherwise it will jump to the else clause.

The problem is probably in your `run_test_case` code, that is never returning True, and so you'll never get the behavior that you're expecting.

It's hard to say without knowing exactly what you want to accomplish, but I'd say that you're missing a `return True` in the end of that code, meaning, if everything executes correctly right until the end, you want it to return True... but I'm only guessing here, you need to think about what that method is supposed to do.

In python an `if` or `elif` clause is evaluated for not only the `True` and `False` constants, but more generally for True-like and False-like values. `None`, for instance, is a false-like value, a non-empty string is a true-like value, etc.

Check this from the documentation on values that are considered true or false:

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: More specifically `run_test_case` returns `None` which is a false-like value.

Comment: Ohh ok but i tried that way also, i put a return True in run_test_cases() but no :(

Comment: Exactly @mgilson I thought it was best to keep it simple, but it's more helpful if the details are further disclosed, I've edited my answer to add a bit more about truthy and falsey values.

Comment: @SRquery don't mention it, if it solves your problem, you can accept the answer.